# How accurate is the De Sitter solution of the Einstein field equations of general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

The De sitter solution models the universe as spatially flat, neglecting ordinary matter, such that it is dominated by the cosmological constant. The cosmological constant notion arguably suggests the existence of dark energy, but exactly how accurate is the model? Can we mathematically prove its accuracy?

Comment: Applies to our universe? Our universe is certainly not de Sitter, if it were then cosmology books would be a lot shorter. But it is a useful approximation at some times.

Comment: I'd suggest that this answer to the related question [What is the geometry of the Universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/70218/104964) ought to be your first port of call.  I would, however, say you cannot prove a physical theory is *accurate* (i.e. matches reality) by mathematics alone.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Anyway, our universe could not be *exactly* de Sitter. This is because we (and earth, planets, large scale structure..), aka inhomogeneities, exist